# Unsupervised learning feature selection in Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, statistics, feature-selection, unsupervised-learning

I need to select the most important features from my data frame before starting with nearest neighbours problem.

Which methods are the best to do this? My data frame has around 8 categorical features and 2 continuous features but no target variable.
The problem is that I have three categorical features which can only be one hot encoded and once I do that it explodes the data into 47 OHE variables.

So considering these situations, what would be the best method to do the feature selection?

Comment: Maybe one direction would be to explore the diversity of each feature one by one...

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Like exploring in what sense?

Comment: @Django0602 have you found anything 'cause I'm having the same problem.